# Como imprimir una respuesta JSON de multiples arreglos con PHP

Tags: php, json, array, curl

le he dado muchisimas vueltas a esta pregunta antes de realizarla pero creo que finalmente luego de horas me di por vencido..

al hacer un request por php recibo una respuesta json la cual puedo imprimir con print_r () pero tiene multiples arreglos dentro de la respuesta, solo he podido imprimir los que estan de primero en el array pero cuanto intento adentrarme para imprimir lo que necesito se me hace imposible

Aqui esta la respuesta que recibo luego de hacer json_decode

```
$array_history=json_decode($resp, true);
foreach($array_history['result'] as $result_history) {
            echo $result_history['txid'];
            echo $result_history['timereceived'];
            echo "<br>";

}
```

Al hacer este foreach anterior si me imprime lo que le solicito ... pero por ejemplo necesito el campo address y qty y no se como llegar a ellos....

> Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [balance] => Array (
>   [amount] => 0 [assets] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => DPR
>   [assetref] => 88-266-22193 [qty] => 2.54 ) ) ) [myaddresses] => Array
>   ( [0] => 1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP ) [addresses] => Array
>   ( [0] => 1UYkAnZccKy2DzXuaiSGuzkhJhZNtFsTJL1cS7 ) [permissions] =>
>   Array ( ) [items] => Array ( ) [data] => Array ( ) [confirmations] =>
>   85 [blockhash] =>
>   009cf5d5b611e7408d12a6b9b74fff81c468685c6a8ce11c3008e12e90a6a247
>   [blockindex] => 1 [blocktime] => 1547310855 [txid] =>
>   112aa56ac6e80461da9cdcaba880a6ae1f246ffddb751245df0ab8969cad21c8
>   [valid] => 1 [time] => 1547310825 [timereceived] => 1547310825 )
>
> [1] => Array ( [balance] => Array ( [amount] => 0 [assets] => Array (
>   [0] => Array ( [name] => DPR [assetref] => 88-266-22193 [qty] =>
>   -56.24758272 ) ) ) [myaddresses] => Array ( [0] => 1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP ) [addresses] => Array ( [0] =>
>   1XXXXXXX4EXXXXXY2EXXXXXXg2XXXXXXZRxjwJ ) [permissions] => Array ( )
>   [items] => Array ( ) [data] => Array ( ) [confirmations] => 80
>   [blockhash] =>
>   0064ac4d9fead866caefdd81779cbd154d4f04e8d7dedf2de23f8cdd79343d7f
>   [blockindex] => 1 [blocktime] => 1547310986 [txid] =>
>   25c3f70896e07d0b3f3e2b321f56ff719d134f293a412f25e94cf64f739ad44a
>   [valid] => 1 [time] => 1547310973 [timereceived] => 1547310973 )
>
> [2] => Array ( [balance] => Array ( [amount] => 0 [assets] => Array (
>   [0] => Array ( [name] => Diprin [assetref] => 71-999-38787 [qty] =>
>   -18.74919424 ) ) ) [myaddresses] => Array ( [0] => 1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP ) [addresses] => Array ( [0] =>
>   1XXXXXXX4EXXXXXY2EXXXXXXg2XXXXXXZRxjwJ ) [permissions] => Array ( )
>   [items] => Array ( ) [data] => Array ( ) [confirmations] => 79
>   [blockhash] =>
>   00d1c1a80a4e7d2f42436d8c4b266febcb309cfb5e0b5a0a7c49e0e6cd88fe93
>   [blockindex] => 1 [blocktime] => 1547311028 [txid] =>
>   6d630d5b400d5e570c7fda3e8645618958dfe001b5d9441d9f304cd275cfc00b
>   [valid] => 1 [time] => 1547311006 [timereceived] => 1547311006 )
>
> [3] => Array ( [balance] => Array ( [amount] => 0 [assets] => Array (
>   [0] => Array ( [name] => DPR [assetref] => 88-266-22193 [qty] =>
>   100000000 ) ) ) [myaddresses] => Array ( [0] =>
>   1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP ) [addresses] => Array ( [0] =>
>   1QkTkZevpa6Jhe9c1CGsUJZAtwuUeYGCpkJESM ) [permissions] => Array ( )
>   [issue] => Array ( [name] => DPR [assetref] => 88-266-22193 [details]
>   => Array ( ) [qty] => 100000000 [raw] => 1.0E+16 [addresses] => Array ( [0] => 1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP ) ) [items] => Array (
>   ) [data] => Array ( ) [confirmations] => 67 [blockhash] =>
>   0069931b3b8fd13cd8f158de90230019cf688e5a0c4ba7a85514a5b7b38909d0
>   [blockindex] => 1 [blocktime] => 1547312508 [txid] =>
>   8081cd2ca8280ce837abeeee48a97b4bfc9495a57a2ca90fe71fe2f3071cee08
>   [valid] => 1 [time] => 1547312476 [timereceived] => 1547312476 )

Comment: Creo que para menos confusión habría sido mejor no convertir el JSON original a array. Siendo así, `qty` se encuentra dentro `balance` (que es un array). Ese array tiene una clave `assets` que a su vez es otro array y es ese array que tiene una clave `qty`, el acceso sería entonces: `$qty=$result_history['balance']['assets'][0]['qty'];` Mientras que `addresses` es una clave dentro de `balance`, que a su vez tiene su valor en la clave `0` de un array. El acceso sería así: `$adr=$result_history['balance']['addresses'][0];` Es lo que se aprecia a simple vista, aunque habría sido mejor que...

Comment: ... mostrases tu `print_r` debidamente identado para poder analizarlo mejor. Para hacerlo, basta con poner algo como `echo "<pre>";  print_r($elArray); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo, asi aparece sin hace json_decode.. {"result":[{"balance":{"amount":0.00000000,"assets":[{"name":"DPR","assetref":"88-266-22193","qty":2.54000000}]},"myaddresses":["1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP"],"addresses":["1UYkAnZccKy2DzXuaiSGuzkhJhZNtFsTJL1cS7"],"permissions":[],"items":[],"data":[],"confirmations":85,"blockhash":"009cf5d5b611e7408d12a6b9b74fff81c468685c6a8ce11c3008e12e90a6a247","blockindex":1,"blocktime":1547310855,"txid":"112aa56ac6e80461da9cdcaba880a6ae1f246ffddb751245df0ab8969cad21c8","valid":true,"time":1547310825,"timereceived":1547310825}

Comment: Y siguen las lineas y lineas de cada ciclo.. ese es solo un ciclo

Answer (score 1):

Como te decía, en estos casos no hace falta que conviertas el JSON a array. Lo puedes dejar como JSON  y trabajar sobre él. Al menos el código es más legible y elegante, porque puedes acceder a los datos mediante la notación:

- `$objeto->propiedad`
- `$objeto[n]` en caso de arrays, donde `n` será el índice

Es importante que aprendas a leer la estructura de tu JSON, o el resultado del `var_dump`, para saber la forma en que debes acceder a cada valor.

He reproducido un JSON de dos elementos con el resultado que pusiste en tu comentario. Por motivos de brevedad he copiado el mismo elemento dos veces, ya que pusiste un resultado con un solo elemento. En estos casos es bueno poner al menos dos elementos para hacer bien las pruebas y ponerlo en el área de la pregunta, no en un comentario.

El JSON que he reproducido es este:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "balance": {
            "amount": 0.00000000,
            "assets": [{
                "name": "DPR",
                "assetref": "88-266-22193",
                "qty": 2.54000000
            }]
        },
        "myaddresses": ["1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP"],
        "addresses": ["1UYkAnZccKy2DzXuaiSGuzkhJhZNtFsTJL1cS7"],
        "permissions": [],
        "items": [],
        "data": [],
        "confirmations": 85,
        "blockhash": "009cf5d5b611e7408d12a6b9b74fff81c468685c6a8ce11c3008e12e90a6a247",
        "blockindex": 1,
        "blocktime": 1547310855,
        "txid": "112aa56ac6e80461da9cdcaba880a6ae1f246ffddb751245df0ab8969cad21c8",
        "valid": true,
        "time": 1547310825,
        "timereceived": 1547310825
    }, {
        "balance": {
            "amount": 0.00000000,
            "assets": [{
                "name": "DPR",
                "assetref": "88-266-22193",
                "qty": 2.54000000
            }]
        },
        "myaddresses": ["1bYufLHsxSoVsxHb812yoVgZJYtFKhZ9funjEP"],
        "addresses": ["1UYkAnZccKy2DzXuaiSGuzkhJhZNtFsTJL1cS7"],
        "permissions": [],
        "items": [],
        "data": [],
        "confirmations": 85,
        "blockhash": "009cf5d5b611e7408d12a6b9b74fff81c468685c6a8ce11c3008e12e90a6a247",
        "blockindex": 1,
        "blocktime": 1547310855,
        "txid": "112aa56ac6e80461da9cdcaba880a6ae1f246ffddb751245df0ab8969cad21c8",
        "valid": true,
        "time": 1547310825,
        "timereceived": 1547310825
    }]
}
```

El *root*  de ese JSON es `results`, y luego tiene un array con varias claves.

- Entre ellas está `balance`, que contiene a su vez una propiedad `assets` con un array dentro de un solo elemento (índice 0) y dentro de ese array otro objeto con varias claves, entre ellas `qty`. Esto te sonará a chino, yo lo describo aquí para que entiendas luego por qué accedo a `$qty` del modo que lo hago en el código.
- En cuanto a `addresses` se encuentra como propiedad de `balance`, pero el valor está dentro de un array, en el índice `0` del mismo. En el JSON, todo lo que esté entre `[]` es un array. Y todo lo que esté entre `{}` es otro objeto JSON anidado.
- `txid` es una propiedad simple del objeto `balance`
- `timereceived` también es una propiedad simple del objeto `balace`

Comprendido esto, veamos la forma de llegar a cada dato:

```
/*
*$s sería la cadena que contiene todo el objeto
*evitamos el TRUE para que lo deje como un JSON
*/
$json=json_decode($s);
/*Accedemos a la propiedad result, que es un array*/
$result=$json->result;
/*Recorremos el array elemento por elemento*/
foreach ($result as $item){
    /*Aplicamos para cada valor lo que ya expliqué arriba*/
    $txid= $item->txid;
    $timereceived=$item->timereceived;
    $qty= $item->balance->assets[0]->qty;
    $addresses= $item->addresses[0];
    echo "txid: $txid".PHP_EOL;
    echo "timereceived: $timereceived".PHP_EOL;
    echo "qty: $qty".PHP_EOL;
    echo "addresses: $addresses".PHP_EOL;
    echo "-----------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**
Los valores son repetidos, porque copié dos veces el mismo elemento. En tu caso debería mostrarse cada valor real:

```
txid: 112aa56ac6e80461da9cdcaba880a6ae1f246ffddb751245df0ab8969cad21c8
timereceived: 1547310825
qty: 2.54
addresses: 1UYkAnZccKy2DzXuaiSGuzkhJhZNtFsTJL1cS7
-----------------------------------------
txid: 112aa56ac6e80461da9cdcaba880a6ae1f246ffddb751245df0ab8969cad21c8
timereceived: 1547310825
qty: 2.54
addresses: 1UYkAnZccKy2DzXuaiSGuzkhJhZNtFsTJL1cS7
-----------------------------------------
```

---

#### Código de prueba

Aquí puedes ver una **<kbd>[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/VLTZU71634)</kbd>** del código y hacer pruebas sobre él.

Con lo he explicado creo que estarás en capacidad de analizar un objeto cualquiera y saber cómo acceder a cualquier valor dentro de él de la manera adecuada.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas Gracias de verdad que mejor explicado nu pudo haber sido...

Answer (score 0):

Explicacion:

Esto `[0] => Array` te indica una posicion del elemento puede variar por numero 0,1,2 dependiendo de la cantidad de resultados
ejemplo:

```
$array_history['result'][0]['balance'];
```

mientras que si no lo tiene es un clave
Ejemplo:

```
$array_history['result'];
```